# How to store data other than text in c++ files

Tags: c++, file, file-io, io, stream

I want to store videos and images in c++ files. Can we store data other than text in **c++** *files*. Like *images*, and *videos*.

Comment: the simple answer is yes, have you tried it? what problem did you encounter?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by c++ file? The .cpp source file can only contains source code, and that is text. If mean to read or write files with a C++ program, than you should search for "c++ io binary file"

Comment: I mean saving image in file using read and write function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you install any picture onto your computer, you can just change the file extension to cpp. The file type is a C++ file, however, if you attempt to read the file it will of course be corrupted and not really make sense.

Changing the extension back to .png or .jpg will restore the image file back to its former glory.